# Where is the port defined in the default IntegrationSpec in the scala play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework

The default integration spec of the scala play framework looks as follows:

```
class IntegrationSpec extends PlaySpec with OneServerPerTest with OneBrowserPerTest with HtmlUnitFactory {

  "Application" should {

    "work from within a browser" in {

      go to ("http://localhost:" + port)

      pageSource must include ("Your new application is ready.")
    }
  }
}
```

Clicking the `port` variable opens the `OneServerPerTest.scala` file:

```
  /**
   * The port used by the `TestServer`.  By default this will be set to the result returned from
   * `Helpers.testServerPort`. You can override this to provide a different port number.
   */
  lazy val port: Int = Helpers.testServerPort
```

Clicking `Helpers.testServerPort` results in:

```
  /**
   * The port to use for a test server. Defaults to 19001. May be configured using the system property
   * testserver.port
   */
  lazy val testServerPort = Option(System.getProperty("testserver.port")).map(_.toInt).getOrElse(19001)
```

Searching for `testserver.port` does not return the variable. How is it possible that the test succeeds while the default port is 9000 and where is `testserver.port` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TestServer` is started using this port, as [you can see here](https://github.com/playframework/scalatestplus-play/blob/master/module/src/main/scala/org/scalatestplus/play/BaseOneServerPerSuite.scala#L170). The port 9000 is the default for development mode, not all the test mode. If you are not setting `testserver.port` property in the command used to start the tests, them the default one (19001) will be used.